# Java jSch Exec with progress bar and real time output to a JTextArea

Tags: java, jsch

I'm developing a program in java to download files directly to my server, for that I'm using jSch to connect via ssh and do a wget command, but i would like to stream the output to a JTextArea, and I've already done that, but it will only print it when the download is finished, and i would like to print it as the output of wget command in real time.

CustomOutputStream code:

```
public class CustomOutputStream extends OutputStream{
private JTextArea textArea;

    public CustomOutputStream(JTextArea textArea) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        // redirects data to the text area
        textArea.append(String.valueOf((char) b));
        // scrolls the text area to the end of data
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getText().length());
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        String s = new String(b,off,len);
        textArea.append(s);
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getText().length());
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        this.write(b, 0, b.length);
    }
```

}

here is the Exec code:

```
Properties props = new Properties(); 
    props.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    int port = 22;

    JSch jsch=new JSch();  

    Session session=jsch.getSession(username, host, 22);
    session.setConfig(props);
    session.setPassword(password);
    session.connect();
    String command =  "cd " + info.downPath + " && printf \"" + downLinks + "\" l> d.txt && wget -i d.txt";
    Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
    InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
    ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
    //((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);
    //((ChannelExec)channel).setOutputStream(System.out);
    ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(new CustomOutputStream(taOutput));
    //((ChannelExec)channel).setOutputStream(new CustomOutputStream(taOutput));
    channel.connect();
    byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
    while(true){
      while(in.available()>0){
        int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
        if(i<0)break;
        System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
      }
      if(channel.isClosed()){
        if(in.available()>0) continue; 
        System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
        break;
      }
      try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
    }
    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
    bar.setValue(100);
```

Comment: OK, so what happens? Is the `CustomOutputStream` ever called? + On what thread do you execute the code?

Comment: It's called, and print it, but only when the download is finished... I would like to stream it in real time.. Img what it prints: http://i.imgur.com/u9NM8su.png

Comment: Here is a gif, how it happens: https://gyazo.com/b583a48d8faf03358a57fb5dabfa4d11

Comment: Thank you! after some search about thread i could make it work the way i wanted =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}

Your code is probably executing on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` and the Thread.sleep(...) is preventing the GUI from repainting itself until the task is finished executing.

So the solution is to start a separate Thread for the long running task so the EDT is able to respond to events.

An easy way do to this is to use a `SwingWorker`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). The tutorial explains more about the `EDT` and `SwingWorker`.

Comment: Thank you =D, after i do some search, i jsut create a new thread to do that task and everything went right.

Answer (score 0):

After some help e more search, i just create a new thread the handler the connection.

Here is the example i took:
from this link :

```
one = new Thread() {
public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Does it work?");

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        System.out.println("Nope, it doesnt...again.");
    } catch(InterruptedException v) {
        System.out.println(v);
    }
}
```

};

one.start();